# MySQL SELECT * from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a very dumb question.
Lets assume that I have 2 tables, A which has 10 rows and B which has 100 rows.
I know that when I enter `SELECT * FROM A, B`, then the result would be 1000 rows.

My question is, why?

Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: What are you trying to do? UNION?

Comment: because it performs a cartesian product between those tables

Comment: each record from first table is associated with each record from second table. How many apples in 100 baskets if each basket has 10 apples?

Comment: Please please please stop joining your tables this way. Whoever is teaching you this method is [wrong](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because this is a [cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join), which gives you a [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) between the two tables.

Wikipedia :

> CROSS JOIN returns the Cartesian product of rows from tables in the
>   join. In other words, it will produce rows which combine each row from
>   the first table with each row from the second table

So in this case, 10 * 100 = (guess what) 1000.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the references !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see 110 resord in the result you should use UNION to combine results from two tables:

```
(SELECT * from A)
UNION
(SELECT * from B)
```

Comment: The question is "why"...

Answer (score 0):

You have to integrate a relation with some WHERE, for edit this output